# How Can I Process Two HTTP Json Request in Same Application

Tags: javascript, json, api, xmlhttprequest

I'm working on a weather app, but it seems the second call to openweather is not working. I know this calls are asynchronous. I don't know if that's the reason they're failing. The first call is made to ipinfo.io it works, but not the second. I would like to know how I could instead of writing to different calls, I could take advantage of writing only one. Don't know if this is possible. any help appreciated
the app

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Weather App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="hero">
    <!-- navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <!-- <img src="/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt=""> -->
        <i class="fa fa-sun-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <strong>Local</strong>Weather
      </a>
    </nav>

    <!-- weather section  -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="" class="col-8 mx-auto weather">
          <div class="weather-head">
            <h2 id="location" class="text-center"></h2>

          </div>
          <div class="weather-body">
            <p class="lead">Hello world</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- javascript functionality -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
      //variables
      var ipUrl = "https://ipinfo.io/json";
      var appid = "8e1880f460a20463565be25bc573bdc6";

      //ip and location info    
      var ipAddr = "";
      var city = "";
      var country = ""
      var latitude = "";
      var longitude = "";

      //weather variables 
      var weatherApi = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&${appid}`;
      var weatherDesc = ""
      var temperature = "";
      var humidity = "";
      var windSpeed = "";

      //http request for ip, location
      var httpReqIp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      httpReqIp.open("GET", ipUrl, true);
      httpReqIp.send();
      //calling processRequest when reques ready
      httpReqIp.onreadystatechange = processIpRequest;

      var location = document.getElementById("location");

      //getting json request when ready
      function processIpRequest(e) {
        if (httpReqIp.readyState == 4 && httpReqIp.status == 200) {
          var jsonResponseIp = JSON.parse(httpReqIp.responseText);
          console.log(jsonResponseIp);
          ipAddr = jsonResponseIp.ip;
          city = jsonResponseIp.city;
          country = jsonResponseIp.country
          latitude = jsonResponseIp.loc.split("-")[0];
          longitude = jsonResponseIp.loc.split("-")[1];
          location.innerHTML = `${city}, ${country}`;
        }
      }

      //http reques for weather info
      var httpReqWeather = new XMLHttpRequest();
      httpReqWeather.open("GET", weatherApi, true);
      httpReqWeather.send(null);
      httpReqWeather.onreadystatechange = processWeatherRequest;

      function processWeatherRequest(e) {
        if (httpReqWeather.readyState == 4 && httpReqWeather.status == 200) {
          var jsonResponseWeather = JSON.parse(httpReqWeather.responseText);
          console.log("Weather: " + jsonResponseWeather);
          weatherDesc = jsonResponseWeather[weather].desc;
          temperature = jsonResponseWeather[main].temp;
          humidity = jsonResponseWeather[main].humidity;
          windSpeed = jsonResponseWeather[wind].speed;
          console.log(weatherDesc + " " + temperature)
        }
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "I don't know if that's the reason they're failing."...in that case look in your browser's console and network tools for error messages, check the ajax call to see what HTTP status and response you get. The tools to debug it are available to you.

Comment: BTW, one thing I notice, your `weatherApi` url string appears to be declared with backticks instead of quotes, not sure that's right. Or is it just a typo in this copy of the code?

Comment: @ADyson Those back ticks denote [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and are valid syntax in ES6.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides thanks I haven't done anything with ES6, that's useful to know